# MongoDB - race condition when replacing an item in a nested array

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

This [open issue](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1050) describes that it's not possible to combine a pull and push of nested items into a single update. Instead, a replace operation is first a pull, then a push.

It seems that this non-isolated transaction occasionally leads to duplicates, i.e. concurrent transactions both execute the pull before the push, ending up with 2 added items.

To protect against that, I came up with a workaround:

```
public async Task ReplaceItem<TItem, TField>(string id, Expression<Func<TDocument, IEnumerable<TItem>>> field, Expression<Func<TItem, TField>> matchField, TField matchValue, TItem value)
{
    // can't update in single operation, see https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1050
    await PullItem(id, field, matchField, matchValue);

    // race condition on parallel requests -> duplicate detection built into query
    var filter = ClientFilter(id) & !Builders<TDocument>.Filter.ElemMatch(field, Builders<TItem>.Filter.Eq(matchField, matchValue));
    var update = Builders<TDocument>.Update.Push(field, value);
    var result = await _collection.UpdateOneAsync(filter, update);

    // ignore that document could have been removed between pull and push
    if (result.MatchedCount != 1)
        throw new RepositoryOperationException("Duplicate item found.");
}

public async Task PullItem<TItem, TField>(string id, Expression<Func<TDocument, IEnumerable<TItem>>> field, Expression<Func<TItem, TField>> matchField, TField matchValue)
{
    var update = Builders<TDocument>.Update.PullFilter(field, Builders<TItem>.Filter.Eq(matchField, matchValue));
    var result = await _collection.UpdateOneAsync(ClientFilter(id), update);

    if (result.MatchedCount != 1)
        throw new RepositoryOperationException("Document not found.");
}
```

Does that make sense or are there better strategies? (I want to avoid refactoring the nested items into full documents)

This runs in the context of a Web API.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to utilize a concurrency pattern to deal with synchronizing tasks.

You can utilize a Monitor, lock is a wrapper around it. You will not have access to .Pulse(), etc. Regardless of it being a WebApi.

```
 private object obj = new object();
 ...
 lock(obj)
 {
    // Critical code
 }
```

Or you can try the Balkin pattern.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_pattern

Comment: Thanks. How would that work in the context of a scalable Web API?

Comment: OK, but the only shared resources between concurrent processes are database and disk... there can be multiple machines.